# Display all the models using API and MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I created a API application where I can perform the crud operations.  However, I am unable to display all the models in my cshtml.
I have created my API controller, which has the getAllUsers methods and in my home controller, I just call the Index View.  In my view, I have a script which calls the getAllUsers methods.  Below is my code:
API controller:

```
namespace WebApiQues.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        private WebApiQuesEntities db = new WebApiQuesEntities();

        //Get all users
        public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            var UserList = from s in db.Users
                           orderby s.Id
                            select s;

            return UserList;
        }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public UserController userController = new UserController();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //var UserList = userController.GetAllUsers();
        //ViewBag.UserList = UserList;
        return View();
    }

}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@model IEnumerable<WebApiQues.Models.User>
<div>

  <div>
    <h2>All Products</h2>
    <ul id="products" />
  </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var uri = 'api/user/getallusers';

      $(document).ready(function () {
          // Send an AJAX request
          $.getJSON(uri)
          .done(function (data) {
              // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
              $.each(data, function (data) {
                  // Add a list item for the product.
                  $('<li>').appendTo($('#products'));
              });
          });
      });
</script>
```

I believe the problem comes from the script in cshtml but I can't find where I am doing it wrong.  Any idea?

EDITED:
If I add a console.log(data), I can see that data has the list of users.

Comment: Did you check if 'getallusers' works fine? I mean either using Fiddler or PostMan

Comment: Yep it works well.   If I type 'http://localhost:3111/api/user/getallusers ',  I get a list of all the users.

Comment: $.getJSON(uri) is referring 'uri', which is incomplete i.e. it should be http://localhost/api/user/getallusers.... Check in fiddler or dev tools of browser and see whats WEB API is getting formed

Comment: Non. the data the script gets, do contain the list of all the models.  I just updated my question.

Comment: It looks to me like you're just appending an empty <li> to your products ul, but you're not using any 'data' in your 'each' function - or have you stripped that part of the code out?

Comment: @Mc Gaz, you are right.  I don't know how I can add the data to the list.  Any idea?

Comment: Try $("#products").append($("<li>").text(data.Id));

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not display any User Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

add your jquery script to the `scripts section:`

```
@section scripts
{
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         var uri = 'api/user/getallusers';
         $.getJSON(uri, function(data) {
             $.each(data, function(index, v) {
                 $('#products').append('<li>'+v.PropertyName+'</li>'); 
                 //Change property name to the property of your object
             });
         });
     });
 </script>
}
```

$.each expects two arguments in the callback function: the index of your array and the actual data object itself:

> callback Type: Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value ) The
>   function that will be executed on every object.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming User has 'Name' property, try this code

```
$.getJSON(uri)
          .done(function (data) {
              // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
              $.each(data, function (data) {
                  // Add a list item for the product.                  
                  $('#products').append('<li>'+data.Name+'</li>');
              });
          });
```

Comment: I tried with a property of User, Fname, but it gives me undefined, instead of the Fname.

Comment: Can you share the console.log(data) output?

Comment: [Object, Object, Object, Object]0: ObjectAge: 20City: "PL"Fname: "A"Id: 1Lname: "Ah"__proto__: Object1: Object2: Object3: Objectlength: 4__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: response data is clumsy or mostly not formatted well. What kind of contract resolver your using in web api i.e. camelCase??

Comment: Nevermind, I got my answer above.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: It is the answer of Ric, above.